# How to set default db schema in tomcat's app context

Tags: tomcat, db2

This this my NXYTEST.xml in tomcat's localhost folder

```
<Context path="/test" reloadable="true" docBase="D:\Development\workspace\NXYTEST\WebContent" workDir="D:\Development\workspace\NXYTEST\work">
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/ebank_ds" password="abc123" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:db2://172.31.17.114:60012/TESTDB" username="con2nns" />
</Context>
```

my project startup and get a db connection, but an error like this:

```
DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC: CON2NNS.PUB_APPPAR caused by: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC: CON2NNS.PUB_APPPAR cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC: CON2NNS.PUB_APPPAR
```

I want to set "testschema" as the default schema, help me, thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to add on to the end of your `url=` this string:

```
:currentSchema=MySchema;
```

So, yours would end up looking like:

```
jdbc:db2://172.31.17.114:60012/TESTDB:currentSchema=testschema;
```